# how to resolve this warning in ASP.Net application?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, assemblies

I get the following as a warning during build of my asp.net application:

> The predefined type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute'
>   is defined in  multiple assemblies in
>   the global alias; using definition
>   from 'c:\Program Files\Reference 
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll'

How do i resolve  this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this blog](http://doogalbellend.blogspot.com/2008/11/predefined-type-is-defined-in-multiple.html):

> So the final solution was to use the InternalVisibleTo attribute in one
>   of the assemblies. This means
>   ExtensionAttribute only needs to be
>   defined in one assembly. There's [more
>   info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx) on how to do that with
>   strongly named assemblies since it's
>   not completely straight forward.

Related question: [C# Compiler Warning 1685](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602927/c-compiler-warning-1685)

Answer (score 0):

from MSDN

> Visual C# Reference: Errors and
>   Warnings Compiler Warning (level 1)
>   CS1685
>
> Error Message The predefined type
>   'System.type name' is defined in
>   multiple assemblies in the global
>   alias; using definition from 'File
>   Name'
>
> This error occurs when a predefined
>   system type such as System.int32 is
>   found in two assemblies. One way this
>   can happen is if you are referencing
>   mscorlib from two different places,
>   such as trying to run the.Net
>   Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1
>   side-by-side.

Based on this, we probably need to see the list of assemblies and their references to help you much.