# Error CS0433 The type 'Task' exists in both System.Threading and mscorlib

Tags: c#, namespaces

I am getting an error in this code:

```
  public async Task SendEmailsTask(List<string> emails)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < emails.Count; i++)
        {

                await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State Error CS0433  The type 'Task' exists in both 'System.Threading, Version=1.0.2856.102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Comment: What namespaces are you referencing?

Comment: using myAlias = System.Threading;

Comment: Also thismight help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408142/the-predefined-type-system-threading-tasks-task-is-defined-in-multiple-assembl

Comment: I can't find a reference to a `Task` in `System.Threading` namespace at all. Should it be `System.Threading.Tasks`?

Comment: You should not be using System.Threading.dll, it was meant to add Task support to apps that target .NET 3.5.  Unclear where it came from, probably a bad Nuget package.  Try to get ahead by simply removing it from your project's References.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the body of your question so the content is not in quotes. Unless you are specifically quoting something, that is not needed. I also formatted the error in code formatting (4 spaces before it), it makes it easier to read. Good day!

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781627/unity-2019-how-to-fix-textmeshpro-2-0-error-cs0433/56456365#56456365

Answer (score -2):

The compiler doesn't know which task you mean as it exists in two libraries. Either use full class names (`System.Threading.Task SendEmailsTask`) or give the namespace an alias

```
using myAlias = System.Threading.Tasks;
```

And reference to it as

```
public async myAlias.Task SendEmailsTask
```