# Unity 2019 - How to fix TextMeshPro 2.0 error cs0433

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, vuforia

I have just started new project that contains Vuforia SDK. After making some changes I decided to install GitHub extension from Asset Store to make some backup. After that my textMeshPro plugin went crazy, throwing an annoying error which I can't deal with. The error says:

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.0\Scripts\Editor\TMP_PackageUtilities.cs(310,17): error CS0433: The type 'Task' exists in both 'System.Threading, Version=1.0.3333.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=402899b480e6f383' and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Does anybody has an idea how to get rid of it?

My Unity version is 2019.1.0f2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The predefined type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408142/the-predefined-type-system-threading-tasks-task-is-defined-in-multiple-assembl)

Comment: TextmeshPro comes by default with Unity 2019, try to delete the plugin

Comment: Thank you for the answer, To fix the problem I needed to downgrade the TextmeshPro in Package Manager.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! i have been fighting this all night. life saver!

Comment: Please don't add "solved" or similar phrases to your question when you've solved the problem. If someone gave you an answer, [accept it](/help/someone-answers). If you found a solution on your own, [post an answer](/help/self-answer) (you can also accept your own answer after two days). Accepting answers is also the way to show a question has been solved - editing "solved" into the question is not. You can recover the answer you edited in [from the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55781627/revisions) if you don't want to re-write the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Thank you for your answers, I have found solution on other forum.

The way to fix the error in unity 2019.1.0f2

1. Go to Window->Package Manager
2. TextMesh Pro (Version 2.0.0 will be installed)
3. Click on the arrow > on the left to see all the available versions.
   4 .Update TextMesh Pro to 1.3.0 (same version as in Unity 2018.3.12f1)
   Let the compiler finish and you should see the error clearing from the console

[image: Picture_tip]

Link to original post: [Original post](https://support.ludiq.io/communities/5/topics/3083-librarypackagecachecomunitytextmeshpro200)

Answer (score 1):

In Unity 2019.1.5 Looks like TextMeshPro needs at least .net ver 4, I changed .net from 3.5 to 4.6 by going: File > Build Settings > Player Settings > Player >  Scripting Runtime Version (which also has a warning on 3.5), selecting 4.6, after reload, textMesh error gone ... moving onto all the other errors in my project!